# Error in creating Xamarin.window phone project in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am a beginner in Xamarin Development. When I create a Xamarin.Forms(portable) project, it creates droid,ios and uwp project and gives the following error when creating window phone OR windows project. I have also tried downloading update by right clicking on the project but same error is appearing again and again. Please help me resolve this problem?

[You can view the Image screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTM7a.png)

Comment: What is the update it recommends?

Comment: Here is Xamarin's guide on adding Windows projects to a Forms solution: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/ . Please go over them and see if it helps you progress.